# why d3d12 runtime don't output any debug message when my app fall in mistake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, directx

In early d3d version like DirectX 11,when i make a mistake,for example , when i use wrong or conflictive argument to create a device or texture/buffer,in visual studio debug output window,there have some message like "d3d11: one or more invalid parameters! " to warning me i was fall in some wrong way.But in DirectX 12,i haven't find any debug message through my work,there is nothing in my vs2015 debug output window except " xxxx's symbol has loaded " and " thread xxx has finished ".

I have installed Windows Graphics Debugger in Setting Window,and i can enable graphics debugger normally in my IDE.

And In debug mode d3d12 debug layer have be enabled and d3d12sdklayer.dll load correctly.

Is somewhere different in new version of DirectX? Or my IED setting is something wrong?
If you can help me with some information ,thanks :)

Comment: Can you please provide an example of exactly what you did in your code that you felt should have produced a warning from the DX12 debug layer?

Comment: Hey,when I create a pipeline state object with imcompatible shader bitcode(for instance, the input layout or rootsignature is incorrect for this vertex shader),the dx12 debug layer will output error to tell me there is something wrong with your code.This is the normal behavior. My IDE will break down immediately and trigger a runtime exception,but not out put any relative message.

Comment: A line of code is better than thousand words